# How to load `.csv` file and get rid the leading and the trailing whitespaces in Google-BigQuery?

Tags: sql, database, csv, google-bigquery

I want to load this `.csv` file bellow to Google-BigQuery.

File `data_transportasi_kajarta.csv` :

```
bulan;tahun;jenis;kode_trayek;trayek;jumlah_penumpang
Januari;2019;BRT;1;KORIDOR 1;2223257
Januari;2019;BRT;2;KORIDOR 2;781605
Januari;2019;BRT;3;KORIDOR 3;919.2
Januari;2019;BRT;4;KORIDOR 4;669417
Januari;2019;ANGKUTAN UMUM LAINNYA ;GR1;BUNDARAN SENAYAN - HARMONI (BUS GRATIS);364618
Januari;2019;ANGKUTAN UMUM LAINNYA ;;RAGUNAN - SMK 57;1927
Januari;2019;ANGKUTAN UMUM LAINNYA ;;MARUNDA-RAGUNAN;112
Januari;2019; ANGKUTAN INTEGRASI BUS KECIL ;JAK-1;TANJUNG PRIOK-PLUMPANG;56764
Januari;2019; ANGKUTAN INTEGRASI BUS KECIL ;JAK-2;DUREN SAWIT - KAMPUNG MELAYU;56551
Januari;2019; ANGKUTAN INTEGRASI BUS KECIL ;JAK-3;LEBAK BULUS - PONDOK LABU;43344
...
...
...
```

But, I just realized that when I set semicolon `;` as the delimiter like bellow, it won't rid the leading and the trailing whitespaces.

[image: Custom delimiter setting in BigQuery]

Actual created table result in my BigQuery:

```sql
| bulan   | tahun | jenis                         | kode_trayek | trayek                                  | jumlah_penumpang |
|---------+-------+-------------------------------+-------------+-----------------------------------------+------------------|
| Januari | 2019  | BRT                           | 1           | KORIDOR 1                               | 2223257          |
| Januari | 2019  | BRT                           | 2           | KORIDOR 2                               | 781605           |
| Januari | 2019  | BRT                           | 3           | KORIDOR 3                               | 919.2            |
| Januari | 2019  | BRT                           | 4           | KORIDOR 4                               | 669417           |
| Januari | 2019  | ANGKUTAN UMUM LAINNYA         | GR1         | BUNDARAN SENAYAN - HARMONI (BUS GRATIS) | 364618           |
| Januari | 2019  | ANGKUTAN UMUM LAINNYA         | null        | RAGUNAN - SMK 57                        | 1927             |
| Januari | 2019  | ANGKUTAN UMUM LAINNYA         | null        | MARUNDA-RAGUNAN                         | 112              |
| Januari | 2019  |  ANGKUTAN INTEGRASI BUS KECIL | JAK-1       | TANJUNG PRIOK-PLUMPANG                  | 56764            | <----- in column `jenis` there is a leading white space
| Januari | 2019  |  ANGKUTAN INTEGRASI BUS KECIL | JAK-2       | DUREN SAWIT - KAMPUNG MELAYU            | 56551            | <----- in column `jenis` there is a leading white space
| Januari | 2019  |  ANGKUTAN INTEGRASI BUS KECIL | JAK-3       | LEBAK BULUS - PONDOK LABU               | 43344            | <----- in column `jenis` there is a leading white space
```

My expectation on the created table result

```sql
| bulan   | tahun | jenis                        | kode_trayek | trayek                                  | jumlah_penumpang |
|---------+-------+------------------------------+-------------+-----------------------------------------+------------------|
| Januari | 2019  | BRT                          | 1           | KORIDOR 1                               | 2223257          |
| Januari | 2019  | BRT                          | 2           | KORIDOR 2                               | 781605           |
| Januari | 2019  | BRT                          | 3           | KORIDOR 3                               | 919.2            |
| Januari | 2019  | BRT                          | 4           | KORIDOR 4                               | 669417           |
| Januari | 2019  | ANGKUTAN UMUM LAINNYA        | GR1         | BUNDARAN SENAYAN - HARMONI (BUS GRATIS) | 364618           |
| Januari | 2019  | ANGKUTAN UMUM LAINNYA        | null        | RAGUNAN - SMK 57                        | 1927             |
| Januari | 2019  | ANGKUTAN UMUM LAINNYA        | null        | MARUNDA-RAGUNAN                         | 112              |
| Januari | 2019  | ANGKUTAN INTEGRASI BUS KECIL | JAK-1       | TANJUNG PRIOK-PLUMPANG                  | 56764            | <----- in column `jenis` there is NO leading white space
| Januari | 2019  | ANGKUTAN INTEGRASI BUS KECIL | JAK-2       | DUREN SAWIT - KAMPUNG MELAYU            | 56551            | <----- in column `jenis` there is NO leading white space
| Januari | 2019  | ANGKUTAN INTEGRASI BUS KECIL | JAK-3       | LEBAK BULUS - PONDOK LABU               | 43344            | <----- in column `jenis` there is NO leading white space
```

> Is it possible to set multiple custom delimiter/separator in the upload setting? So, I could have two delimiter or more, in example: `;`, `;` , and  `;`
>
> If it is possible to do, how can I achieve it?

Comment: You can simply use a string function like [`LTRIM()`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#ltrim) as `SELECT LTRIM('   string') as trimmed;`

Comment: @JihoChoi I know that we could do with `TRIM`, `LTRIM`, or `RTRIM`. But what I want to achieve is I want the data in each cell is trimmed and then stored without any leading and trailing whitespaces. I don't want to use `TRIM` each time I do a query from the table. Is it possible to achieve that by adjusting from the upload file setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately  in BigQuery I do not believe you can use multiple custom delimiter/separator because it does not have the OR logic, it is designed to load your data and not transform it.

If you definitely don't want to transform the data in Bigquery using the `TRIM` function and can not clean the data at source then the other option is to use a program like `python` and `trim` and upload the data at the same time.

These to links contain the snippets you would require to do this

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/python-trim-string-rstrip-lstrip-strip

https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-upload-data-to-google-bigquery-using-python-in-3-steps-7138ae625fe3

Comment: So the only way to clean the data using something like `pandas` in python right? Alright thanks. I'll try that later 